# How to fix this 'Xcode14 - iOS16' keyboard strange UI problem?

Tags: swift, ios16, xcode14

There is a func to change the return key type of the keyboard.

```
func refreshReturnKeyType() {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    textView.returnKeyType = .default
    textView.reloadInputViews()
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

When i build this code with Xcode13, everything is fine. The returnKeyType can be changed smoothly, the keyboard is refreshed.

However, when i build this code with Xcode14 on an iOS16 iphone, there is some UI problem. The keyboard will draw back and then pop up again. Obviously, `resignFirstResponder` makes the keyboard draw back and `becomeFirstResponder` makes the keyboard pop up.

Has anyone ever met this problem? how to fix it? Thanks！

1. Xcode13 - iOS15 - fine
2. Xcode13 - iOS16 - fine
3. Xcode14 - iOS15 - fine
4. Xcode14 - iOS16 - not fine

Xcode14.2 is the same as Xcode14.1